# PHP - How to Convert Javascript Array to PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm using PHP and MySql for my web application.

In Mysql I'm inserting string as JavaScript Array `["0","1","2","3","4","5","6"]`

Now I'm retrieving value from database and save in PHP Variable `$dow`

I need to Convert this to PHP Array like `$dow = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in PHP for decoding JSON string.

```
$row = json_decode('["0","1","2","3","4","5","6"]');
```